# Transparent Activity opening independently

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-pendingintent, start-activity

I want to create a activity with transparent background that I can start by clicking on a Notification.

I created the notification and the activity with no problem, but now, I want to open this particular **TransparentActivity** independently i.e. without showing the other activities on the background.

I tried to put some flags on the intent:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
```

and on the AndroidManifest file, on my TransparentActivity tag, I put:

```
<activity
    android:name=".TransparentActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

It works as expected, but now I have **two icons** for my app, which is something I don't want.

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Add: `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`

Comment: It did not work. Should I do something else other than adding this new flag?

Comment: To understand you situation, can you post screenshot of **two icons** ?

Comment: I don't have a screenshot right now (I can send it later) but Android will create one icon for every single activity with the intent filter "LAUNCHER" when installing the app.

Comment: You should remove the `<intent-filter>` for your `TransparentActivity`. You don't need that. Android creates an application icon for each and every `Activity` that has an `<intent-filter>` with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to change the `taskAffinity` for this `Activity` in the manifest. Add:

```
android:taskAffinity=""
```

to the `<activity> declaration for this one`Activity`.

This one `Activity` will then be launched into a new task, and not into the task that runs the rest of your application.

Comment: I was using task affinity, but "singleTask" instead of "singleInstance". I read the tasks and back-stack documentation, and I was sure "singleTask" was the one I was looking for. Using "singleInstance" worked for me, thanks :D

Comment: I don't know why you edited my answer and added the word "singleInstance" to the `taskAffinity` declaration. This has nothing to do with launchMode and that edit certainly confused the matter. You set the `taskAffiinity` to an empty string and that means that the `Activity` has no affinity for any other activities, so it can run in any task. In reality it makes no difference that string you use, but using the string "singleInstance" could surely confuse people. I reedited my answer.

Comment: Looking at your original post, you are not using `taskAffinity`, you are using `launchMode="singleTask"`.

Comment: I'm sorry about editing your question. I confused `launchMode` with `taskAffinity` and I'm very glad you changed it back :) Once more, thank you very, very much for your help.

Comment: Commenting on an old thread, but I too ran into this issue and this is further explained at https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation#ExtendedNotification.